# Jcrop OnSelect in Directive Not Firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a directive for Jcrop in a project I'm working on. For some reason, the function I have specified in Jcrop's [OnSelect](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html#Event_Handlers) isn't firing. I'm wondering if it's because I've defined it within the link function in my directive, or if it's another scope issue...but I'm not really sure.

I'm defining the following directive for Jcrop:

```
module MyProject.Directives {

    export interface IEfJcropScope extends ng.IScope {
        image: MyProject.Image;
        aspectRatioGroups: _.Dictionary<MyClass[]>;
        selectCrop(group: MyClass[]);
        storeCoords(coords);
    }

    export class EfJcrop implements ng.IDirective {
        restrict = "E";
        templateUrl = 'ef-jcrop.html';
        replace = true;
        transclude = true;
        scope = {
            image: "="
        }
        link = (scope: IEfJcropScope, elem, attrs) => {
            window.setTimeout(() => {
                this.imageElement = $('#img-' + scope.image.ImageID)
                this.imageElement.Jcrop({
                    onChange: scope.storeCoords, //this is not firing
                    onSelect: scope.storeCoords, //this is not firing
                    allowResize: false,
                    allowSelect: false,
                }, () => {

                    });
            });
            //passing in an entire group, represents all active products for one particular aspect ratio
            scope.selectCrop = (group: MyClass[]) => { 
                var jcropObj = this.imageElement.data('Jcrop');
                jcropObj.setOptions({
                    aspectRatio: 1.5 //for example
                });
                scope.storeCoords = (coords) => {
                    //store coords.x, coords.y, code is here
                }
            }
        };
        controller = ($scope: IEfJcropScope) => {
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the template:

```
<div class="ef-jcrop">
    <div ng-controller="imagectrl">
        <img id="img-{{image.id}}"
             src="placeholder"
             ng-attr-alt="{{image.name}}"
             ng-src="{{image.url}}" />

        <table id='productRatioTable'>
            <tr class="ratio-selection">
                <td class="ratio-item" ng-repeat="group in aspectRatioGroups">
                    <img id="ratio{{$index}}" ng-src="{{image.url}}" class='ratioSelector' ng-click="selectCrop(group)" ng-class="{ 'selected' : group.selected }" />
                    <div ng-repeat="ipd in group">{{ipd.ProductDimension.Name}}</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

With a breakpoint in `scope.storeCoords`, the function is never reached. I get no errors in the browser. Why wouldn't it be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue that resulted from a tired brain. The `storeCoords` is within the `selectCrop` function. It shouldn't be. Oops.